# Using JSON configs and casting datatypes with Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am using a JSON configuration with the typesafehub configuration library. I need to cast the `Double` values to `Float` as JSON only holds "numbers" without specifying whether they are `Float` or `Double`. This goes for the other data types as well, such as `Byte`, `Short`, etc.

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
public <T> T getNumber(String path, Class<T> clazz) {
    Number number = this.config.getNumber(path);
    // Or alternatively, I can also get an Object or Double value
    // Double dub = this.config.getDouble(path);
    // Object obj = this.config.getValue(path).unwrapped();

    if (clazz == Byte.class) {
        return clazz.cast(number.byteValue());
    } else if (clazz == Short.class) {
        return clazz.cast(number.shortValue());
    } else if (clazz == Integer.class) {
        return clazz.cast(number.intValue());
    } else if (clazz == Long.class) {
        return clazz.cast(number.longValue());
    } else if (clazz == Float.class) {
        return clazz.cast(number.floatValue());
    } else if (clazz == Double.class) {
        return clazz.cast(number.doubleValue());
    }

    // Will usually return cast exception if not of type Double
    return clazz.cast(number);
}
```

The optimal solution would be just casting it directly however, if I try to cast the `Object` to a `Float` or I receive a cast exception due to the original type not being defined at compile time (and therefore it obviously won't let me cast a `Object/Double Object` to a Float like that.

My solution works, but it seems extremely long winded for what I want to do. All I am trying to do is fetch different data types from a configuration which stores numbers primarily as Doubles. The only other alternative is to have a separate method for each cast:

```
public float getFloat(String path) {
    return (float) this.config.getDouble(path);
}
```

Are there any solutions I am missing? I would rather not have a huge nested if statement but it seems like generics isn't very useful in this context despite being helpful overall.

Comment: And there's no way through the `config` instance to possibly pass in your class and get a type in that manner?

Comment: No way, look at [this class overview](https://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html).

Comment: Why have this at all? What's the benefit over just calling the specific `fooValue` method instead of passing it's class. i.e. `float f = obj.getNumber("SomePath", Float.class);` vs. `float f = obj.getNumber("SomePath").floatValue();`

Comment: I already do this in the internals, but because this is one part of a bigger backend library, I want to make it as simple as possible for newcomers to the library. That's the only key reason as well as this sparking my curiosity.